# Adding configurable product to cart in Magento 1.8.0.0 sets wrong price

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8, configurable

I'm trying to add multiple configurable products at once to the cart in Magento.
The code I used for this is:

```
    $postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
    $superAttributes = $postData['super_attribute'];
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    if(isset($postData['bundleconfigurable']) && !empty($postData['bundleconfigurable'])){
        foreach($postData['bundleconfigurable'] as $optionId => $qtyArray){
            foreach($qtyArray as $valueId => $qty){
                if($qty < 1){
                    continue;
                }

                // Add items to cart
                $itemSuperAttributes = $superAttributes;
                $itemSuperAttributes[$optionId] = $valueId;

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($postData['product']);

                $params = array(
                    'product' => $postData['product'],
                    'super_attribute' => $itemSuperAttributes,
                    'qty' => $qty
                );

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->load($postData['product']);
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            }
        }
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I believe the code should be correct.
A sample output of the $params:

Array ( [product] => 2287 [super_attribute] => Array ( [179] => 1203 [154] => 626 ) [qty] => 1 )

When redirecting to the cart page, everything is added nicely (the super attributes are just fine), but the price of the product is wrong. I've checked the numbers in the $params (179=>1203, etc) and they match with the options chosen.

Please find a screenshot below of the configuration and of the shopping cart.

Configuration:
[image]

Chosen options:
[image]

Result in cart:
[image]

So as you can see, the options are just fine, but the price is from another combination (IDS 2255 - 2259).

Any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Thanks!